# Tramp with ssh not asking for password - too many authentication failures

Tags: tramp, ssh, remote

I would like to use tramp to login to a remote server via SSH.

It used to work effortlessly, but somehow it does not even ask me for a password any longer and tries wildly to login with I guess keys from `~/.ssh` or something, until the server gives me:

`Received disconnect from MYSERVER port 22:2: Too many authentication failures`

How do I force tramp to not try anything, but always use password authentication? I also do not wish to use an authentication file currently. I have found many questions where an authentication file was the chosen solution, but I would like to stick with Emacs asking me for a password for now. I am looking for the tramp equivalent of:

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no MYUSER@MYSERVER
```

I already have the following in my `init.el`:

```
;; ==========
;; TRAMP MODE
;; ==========
(setq tramp-default-method "ssh")
(setq tramp-verbose 5)
(setq password-cache-expiry 86400)
(setq auth-source-debug t)
(setq auth-sources '())
```

I also have a hunch, that it might be, that tramp does not notice, that the server asks for a password, because of a custom MOTD, but am not sure, that this is the issue. The MOTD looks like this:

```
#####################################
#####################################
#                                   #
#      LOGGING IN TO MYSERVER       #
#                                   #
#####################################
#####################################
MYUSER@MYSERVER's password:
```

## Versions

- tramp: `tramp 2.2.13.25.2 built-in`
- emacs: `GNU Emacs 25.2.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.21) of 2017-09-22, modified by Debian`

## Output in debug tramp/ssh

```
#####################################
#####################################
#                                   #
#      LOGGING IN TO MYSERVER       #
#                                   #
#####################################
#####################################
Received disconnect from MYSERVERIP port MYSERVERPORT:2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from MYSERVERIP port MYSERVERPORT
23:31:27.476717 tramp-maybe-open-connection (3) # Opening connection for MYSERVERUSER@MYSERVERIP using ssh...failed
23:41:32.631334 tramp-get-test-command (5) # Finding a suitable ‘test’ command
23:41:32.632857 tramp-maybe-open-connection (3) # Opening connection for MYSERVERUSER@MYSERVERIP using ssh...
23:41:32.641165 tramp-maybe-open-connection (3) # Sending command ‘exec ssh -l MYSERVERUSER  -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none MYSERVERIP’
23:41:32.643068 tramp-process-actions (3) # Waiting for prompts from remote shell...
23:41:33.474487 tramp-process-one-action (5) # Looking for regexp "\(.*\(user\|login\)\( .*\)?: *\)\'" from remote shell
23:41:33.477166 tramp-process-one-action (5) # Looking for regexp "\(^.*\(\(?:adgangskode\|contrase\(?:\(?:ny\|ñ\)a\)\|geslo\|h\(?:\(?:asł\|esl\)o\)\|iphasiwedi\|jelszó\|l\(?:ozinka\|ösenord\)\|m\(?:ot de passe\|ật khẩu\)\|pa\(?:rola\|s\(?:ahitza\|s\(?: phrase\|code\|ord\|phrase\|wor[dt]\)\|vorto\)\)\|s\(?:alasana\|enha\|laptažodis\)\|wachtwoord\|лозинка\|пароль\|ססמה\|كلمة السر\|गुप्तशब्द\|शब्दकूट\|গুপ্তশব্দ\|পাসওয়ার্ড\|ਪਾਸਵਰਡ\|પાસવર્ડ\|ପ୍ରବେଶ ସଙ୍କେତ\|கடவுச்சொல்\|సంకేతపదము\|ಗುಪ್ತಪದ\|അടയാളവാക്ക്\|රහස්පදය\|ពាក្យសម្ងាត់\|パスワード\|密[码碼]\|암호\)\).*:
```

It seems to me that the "sending command" part: `Sending command ‘exec ssh -l MYSERVERUSER  -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none MYSERVERIP’` is wrong, or at least not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said which Tramp version you are using. However, recent Tramp versions use the `auth-source` package for getting the password from an authentication file. In order to disable this, just eval `(setq auth-sources nil)`.

Comment: I added version information in the question. Setting to `nil` instead of `'()` (I was too much in my Scheme mind set.) did unfortunately not change anything. I still get the "too many authentication failures" message without a chance to enter a password.

Comment: Well, your MOTD could be interpreted by Tramp as shell prompt. Just a wild guess. I recommend to adapt `tramp-shell-prompt-pattern` and `shell-prompt-pattern`. If this doesn't help, pls write a bug report; analysis of the trace files is out of scope of stackexchange.

Comment: I think that is some regex I need adapt. If I find a solution, I will add it here. Thanks!